# onGesturePerformed not recognizing gestures, always returning null

Tags: android, gesture-recognition, gestures

I've read up on gestures in android and even found a similar issue on this site but the solution was not given. So I'm asking it again.

I would like to use GestrueOverlay to flip through a view switcher. I ran gesturebuilder, moved the gesture file in my res/raw, added the overlay in my XML and implemented the listener. I basically copied the code from the google instructions.

I can see the listener tracking the gesture, changing from faded yellow to dark yellow, but it will not recognize the gesture. I wrote a toast to find out the size of the prediction and it always reads ZERO.

Please help, and thank you for your time.

here is the onCreate code

```
      mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(LayoutView.getContext(), R.raw.gestures);
      gestures = (GestureOverlayView) LayoutView.findViewById(R.id.gestures);     
      gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
```

here is the listener code

```
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);
    Toast.makeText(LayoutView.getContext(), String.valueOf(predictions.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // We want at least one prediction
    if (predictions.size() > 0) {
        Prediction prediction = (Prediction) predictions.get(0);
        // We want at least some confidence in the result
        if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
            // Show the spell
            Toast.makeText(overlay.getContext(), prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same issue as I had, I figured I'd post my solution. You have to load the gesture library after you define it. i thought

```
  mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(LayoutView.getContext(), R.raw.gestures);
```

loaded the gestures from the resources, and that mLibrary.load was just a boolean if the load was successful. my mistake is that i did not use that method. In fact, you have to also use the load method on the library to load the gestures.

newbie mistake, you live and learn.